# getCollection returns active products without status filter

Tags: magento-1.7, product, collection, product-attribute

I am getting product collection without using `addAttributeToFilter('status',array('eq'=>,1))`,but still my collection has only active products.

Why it returns active products default?Is there any values set for this in admin?

My Full code is,

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addCategoryFilter($category)
    ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id',array('neq'=>$current->getId()))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('name',array('eq'=>$current->getName()))
    ->addAttributeToSort('price', 'asc')
    ->addFieldToFilter($attr_brand['code'], $attr_brand['val']);
```

Comment: show us full collection code that you have tried

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a hunch you have the flat products enabled.
The flat tables generated by the flat product indexer contain only active products.
This is for performance reasons. There is no need to index the disabled products since you are not going to use them on frontend. (and the flat tables are used only on frontend).

If you are trying to get your products in a custom script and you need to get the disabled ones also you can do this.

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->...add filters in here if needed.
```

Comment: But @Marius using `getModel()` is better than `getResourceModel()` right?

Comment: Where did you get that idea?

Comment: I am not sure..But `getResourceModel()` is an another layer in magento(in my mind).If I am wrong what is the difference?

Comment: @Manik. In most cases `getModel('model')->getCollection()` is the same thing as `getResourceModel(model_collection)`. There is a difference only for categories and products. When the flat catalog is enabled they return different things depending if you are on frontend or backend.  Calling `getResourceModel` bypasses this process and returns directly the resource you want. If you want to dig deeper and learn what happens you can add some logs in `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract::getResourceCollection` then work with flat catalog enabled and disabled and see the differences.

Comment: you are absolutely correct.I wondered The code i used produce different result when it is in adminhtml page.why this thing happens?

Comment: Because the method Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product_Flat::isEnabled returns different values for admin and frontend. And that method is used when initializing the product model and linking it to a resource mode.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17865/discussion-between-manik-and-marius).

Answer (score 0):

Flat Products only contains active products...