# How to get all Products including disabled in Magento 1.3

Tags: product, category, flat-catalog, magento-1.3

I have spent hours trying to find how to get a simple thing like all products - including the disabled ones.

My apologies , this is such an old version! I have looked up most of the posts on stack exchange etc to do this.  the closest I have got is [This post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/40000/getcollection-returns-active-products-without-status-filter/40001#40001)

In my code below , $products and $allProducts give me exactly the same amount , leaving out 200+ disabled products.

- This is Magento 1.3
- I do have flat catalog product & category switched on , and I want to run this script fairly regularly and don't want to have to switch it off.
- I have read several other stack overflow etc. posts that don't work either.

Any Ideas how I can get all products in Magento 1.3 including the disabled ones?

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/json');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

require_once('./app/Mage.php');
Mage::app();

$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();

$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'DESC')
    ->load();



$allProducts = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');

echo $products->getSize();
echo $allProducts->getSize();

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following way:

```
$newStoreId = Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID;
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage::getModel('core/store')->load($newStoreId));

$productCollection = $category->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```

Now you will able to get all products. But one problem here, that is product url. So use following code if you need url as well:

```
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore('default');
foreach ($productCollection as $product) {

}
```

Comment: I can't thank you enough!  I did need to change the code because I am not using a category ( so you may want to change your answer )   , but it does the job in Magento 1.3.   thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use this code. You'll get **disabled product collection** using this code.

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('eq' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_DISABLED));
```

Comment: Thanks ,  good answer for the filtering , but you do need to set the current store first ( as above ) .  thank you for your time.